# chrome extension development: suggestions with images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I'm making a chrome extension, And I'm trying to add that Omnibox thing... When the user enters the text I'd like to make a call to the API & then show the results like this:

[image]

but I couldn't find any guide or tutorial to do so, So one is it possible & two how can I achieve the same result?

Comment: No, extensions can't do that, see https://crbug.com/1072167

Comment: Take a look at the [OmniBox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox), you can do this but only after a keywords is typed.

Comment: @Titus I know that But so far I only found a way to show suggestions as text using {content:'...', description:'...',}, I'm looking for a way to add an image to each suggestion